# What has been the problem with the question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have some questions relating to [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/185156/conjecture-reference-request). Actually I can't seem to figure out what has gone wrong with the question.

In my view, it was not off-topic. Perhaps my representation may be vague. In any case, wouldn't it be better to leave a comment suggesting the possible modifications?

I am not asking this question just because I got downvotes. I only suggest that if the users of MO don't consider my question to be suitable and hence downvote, it will be beneficial and better for me if they leave a comment saying what are the difficulties in the question. I think that this procedure will help, not only me but also my fellow MO users to some extent.

Comment: I think you are right -- it would be helpful if people were to give their honest criticisms. It might be that the question has easy answers (in the form of not mere conjectures but also known facts) and thus is too broad or unconstrained. Maybe if you were to put constraints on $f$ and indicate why you think a specific result is true (perhaps by adducing empirical evidence or other research effort), the question would get a better reception.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are the author of the paper you linked to? (This wasn't clear from the wording of your question)

Comment: @YemonChoi: No. I am not the author of the paper. [This user](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/153012/user153012) gave the link in his answer to one of my question.